# Schema markup for list pages

Tags: schema.org, technical-seo

Let's take a **blog** as an example which lists just the article titles and dates on one page. Every article than has its own page.

The individual article pages have their individual schema markups for the given post.

Should we include schema markup in the **list page** for the list of articles even if that page only has the title and date for each article?

Or is that harmful / just going to confuse the search engine?

Comment: What schema are you thinking of using on the list page?  [ItemList](https://schema.org/ItemList)?  Which rich snippet in the search engine results are hoping to get?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was under the impression schema markup was also used to generally assist search engines, I was not thinking of rich snippets for the list page. In that light, I guess schema markup is not needed here, although ItemList is mildly intriguing. Thank you for the suggestion! Feel free to convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: [Structured data doesn't help rankings at all](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/980902538865205248)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yepp, I was thinking about relevancy rather than ranking.